# How do filter in immutable js with a filterchanging at each iteration?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, filtering, immutable.js

I'm trying to filter an immutable.js Map object with values from a Set object in such a way that when a value matches in the set it is removed from the set for subsequent iterations.

The code for filtering without consuming from the set seems straightforward

```
const keyVals = Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 2, d: 3, e: 1});
const wantedVals = Set([2,3]);
const wantedKeyVals = keyVals.filter(v => wantedVals.includes(v));   // expect Map({b: 2, c: 2, d: 3})
```

How would you change the code to consume matched values from the set giving the filter result Map({b: 2, d: 3})?

I guess I need to pass in a new immutable set at each iteration but cannot see how to code this.